# Find out which database a stored procedure is in

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a list of stored procedure ids and names and i need to find out which database in the server they are located. Is there an easy way to do this? Like a system table that stores this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for this type of query you would need to loop through the list of databases (perhaps using `sp_MSforeachdb`) and query the individual system tables in each database.

The below might work for you though which avoids this. The first method checks `object_id` and `name` but doesn't do any validation that the objects are actually stored procedures.

The second one just uses name as requested in the comments, does also validate object type, but only checks the default schema.

```
WITH objects(name, id)
     AS (SELECT 'uspGetBillOfMaterials', 23671132 UNION ALL
         SELECT 'uspPrintError', 37575172) SELECT 'Using Id and Name',
       sys.databases.name,
       objects.name
FROM   sys.databases,
       objects
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME(id, database_id) = objects.name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Using Name (assumes default schema)',
       sys.databases.name,
       objects.name
FROM   sys.databases,
       objects
WHERE  OBJECT_ID(databases.name + '..uspGetBillOfMaterials', 'P') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Very cool, does exactly what i needed. Thanks! How would the code change if it was just the name i had? Just thinking as i need to do this with other objects in the future and i might not have the id. It does mean that the validation isnt a problem though. Thanks again.

Comment: @jimminybob - If you only had the name it wouldn't work because it leverages the fact that `OBJECT_NAME` accepts a second parameter for database id. This isn't the case for the inverse function `OBJECT_ID`. You'd need to query the database catalogue views individually in that case.

Comment: Actually this would be possible if you also knew the schema or could assume default schema.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl.

```
DROP TABLE #Databases

CREATE TABLE #Databases (ID INTEGER IDENTITY (0,1), DbName NVARCHAR(128))

INSERT INTO #Databases(DbName)
SELECT name FROM sys.databases

DECLARE @CurrentID INTEGER = 0,
        @MaxID     INTEGER = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Databases)

DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(128) = (SELECT DbName FROM #Databases WHERE ID = @CurrentID),
        @SqlCommand   VARCHAR(MAX)



WHILE (@CurrentID <= @MaxID)
BEGIN
    SET @SqlCommand = 'SELECT name,ROUTINES.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA,ROUTINES.SPECIFIC_NAME 
                       FROM sys.databases AS DatabaseNames
                       INNER JOIN ' + @DbName + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES AS ROUTINES
                               ON ROUTINES.SPECIFIC_CATALOG = DatabaseNames.name
                       WHERE ROUTINES.ROUTINE_TYPE = ''PROCEDURE'' 
                        AND ROUTINES.SPECIFIC_NAME IN (''X'',''Y'')'

   EXEC (@SqlCommand)

   SET @CurrentID = @CurrentID + 1
   SELECT @DbName = DbName 
   FROM #Databases 
   WHERE ID = @CurrentID

END
```